# I can change value of only one register on 8-Bit Register integrated circuit (74hc273 / DM74LS273)?

Tags: arduino-nano, memory, multiplexer

First, please be patient, I'm not electronical person. I am learning Arduino and electronics for hobby and this is my fist time with integrated circuits.

- Situation: I'm want to extend the Arduino Nano pins (De/Multiplexer) and keep the state (High/Low) of the new pins until I decide to change it again. For keep the states I think that D-type Flipflop memory-based system can help .
- **Question 1**: On this system can  I change only one bit with a unique signal or need to set all bit states ?
- Example (reference image):

1. Memory, previous state: `Q0=0, Q1=1, Q2=1, Q3=0`
2. Arduino: **Set pin17** (D2) **to High** -> Memory: Waiting new data.
3. Arduino: **Set pin16** (D3) **to High** -> Mux: Pass the value to memory at **D0**
4. Memory: **Read 1 on D0** (this is my doubt. D1, D2 and D3 don't matter ?)
5. Arduino: **Set pin17** (D2) **to LOW** -> Memory: Save new data
6. Memory, new state: `Q0=1, Q1=1, Q2=1, Q3=0` ? ***or*** `Q0=1, Q1=0, Q2=0, Q3=0` ?

**Question 2**: Are this correct ?
**Question 3**: Are there a more efficient way to do this?

[image]

**Notes:**

- I used a simulator to diagramed the memory based on this datasheet: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/8337/NSC/74273.html It seems that it is possible, but I want to be sure.
- My currently solution is use separated flipflops, but I want to simplify it.
- Connections on reference image are simplified.
- Sorry about the poor diagram, I don't know programs for beautiful electronical diagrams.
- Sorry about typos, not-native English person here.

Comment: I don't want to answer in a comment, but have you heard of the 74HC595 chip? That lets you set up 8 outputs using only 3 pins from the Arduino, and they can be chained. That looks simpler than your proposal.

Comment: Or if you want even fewer outputs used you could consider an I2C IO expander like the MPC23017.

Comment: feeding demux into the latch will not let you set output pins to various states

Comment: There is a simple and cheap component that can do what you want, the [74HC259 addressable latch](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT259.pdf). Essentially it's demux and an 8-bit latch in which the bits are individually addressable.

Comment: Look at the data sheet of the '273: You cannot set its flip-flops individually. All or none, that's it. Use another IC.

Comment: A lot of thanks for your comments. Really appreciate your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1** and **Question 2**: I was wrong, this is not the correct way. *@jsotola* and *@the_busybe*e, thanks for the clarification

**Question 3**: *@Nick_Gammon* and *@Majenko* I think you are right, using i2c are more efficient ways to do. But, the *@StarCat* proposal is more compatible with my current solution. **74hc259** allows me set the state one by one and keep it until I change it again.